# Wrong icon for a .odg files (Libreoffice Draw), Ubuntu 14.04, Libreoffice 4.2.4.2

Tags: 14.04, libreoffice

Have strange issue.
The .odg files made with Libreoffice Draw have wrong icon (as shown below).

[image]

Other open document formats from Libreoffice have icons similar to application icons.

I have Ubuntu 14.04 installed with native Unity, Ambiance and ubuntu-mono-dark theme. Libreoffice 4.2.4.2 has "galaxy-style" set of icons (but it doens't affect files icons, as far as I know).

All associations are set correctly. All the png/svg files for "libreoffice-draw" in /usr/share/applications/app-install seem to be correct. I don't even know from where this wrong icon was taken.

How it can be fixed? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is also the icon I see for `.odg` files. I think it is the intended default icon.

Looking in the Properties after right-clicking on a `.odg` file, I found it said `application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics` in parentheses under "Type:".  Then I found the corresponding file:

`/usr/share/icons/Humanity/mimes/48/application-vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics`

Looking in its properties that file was actually just a link to this file, which is the image displayed as the `.odg` icon:

`/usr/share/icons/Humanity/mimes/48/x-office-drawing.svg`

The image you want to change to is at:

`/usr/share/icons/Humanity/mimes/48/libreoffice-oasis-drawing.svg`

All you have to do is replace `x-office-drawing.svg` with the new icon you want (i.e. delete the old file, copy a new file to that directory, then rename it). There are actually a bunch of different size folders (e.g. 32, 48, 128) so I wrote the following bash script. This worked on my system. Just save it using a text editor as `change-icon.sh`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

path="/usr/share/icons/Humanity/mimes"
orig="application-vnd.oasis.opendocument.drawing.svg"
new="x-office-drawing.svg"

for dir in $(find "$path" -type d ! -path "$path"); do
    sudo cp "$dir"/"$orig" "$dir"/"$new"
done

sudo gtk-update-icon-cache "/usr/share/icons/Humanity"
```

Then make it executable:

`chmod +x change-icon.sh`

Execute it with:

`./change-icon.sh`

You will probably get some error messages from `cp`. This is normal since not all of the folders have the files for some reason. You also might have to log out and back in to see the changes.

Comment: Thanks! But all the new-created files still have the first icon...

Comment: Whoops, I gave you the instructions to change a specific file's icon rather than all icons for a file type. I'll edit my answer shortly.

Comment: Wrote a bash script to take care of the annoying copy and paste of a bunch of different files.

Comment: Thank you very much))) This "change-icon.sh" worked perfectly for me even without logging out!

Comment: Sadly, in Nautilus 3.4.2 the icons didn't change when using compact or list mode... Ubuntu 12.04.5, Libreoffice 3.5.7. Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have access to a 12.04 machine, but I updated my answer to include some more details so you can follow the process. Basically I just right-clicked a `.odg` file and looked under "Type:" in its Properties. Then I searched my system for `vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics` to find the folders. Note in this case the first file was actually a link to `x-office-drawing.svg` which is the actual icon file. Replacing the icon file with another (same filename) should change the icon for all `.odg` files. Good luck :)

Comment: Also you might want to make sure that all of the icons have been replaced in all of the folders.  On my system I have folders for 16, 22, 24, 32, 48, 64, 128, and 256.  If a different view with different size icons isn't working I'd check the folders for the smaller icon sizes.

Comment: Thank you one more time, TheSchwa. Such a mess out there in Hhumanite mime folders))) So I decided to remove the whole folder and "sudo install --reinstall humanity-icon-theme". Have to live with all this incorrect icon stuff)))